# Can Spivak's 5-volume series on differential geometry be effective without exercises?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question

I was scouring the internet for information about these books and I learned that the latter 4 volumes have no exercises. Would I be able to attain mastery with no exercises?

Comment: exercises not necessarily had to be gathered at the end of sections or chapters

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm confused. Are you suggesting that I go somewhere else for the exercises?

Comment: usually authors do not write all the details of a theory, is the oneself duty to complete the gaps as exercises

Comment: I understand that, but reviews on the series state that volumes 2-5 contain zero exercises. The books were all nonetheless rated very highly.

Comment: the book is one-big-exercise then

Answer (score 0):

I think I have been terribly misinformed. I've looked over the five volumes on scribd and noticed that only the second volume lacks any problems.